# jquery mutiple selects table or grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi I'm trying to find a plugin that allowS mutiple selection of cells - like excel by holding the control key down (although holding the mouse button down and dragging accross a grouping of rows and cols would be equally acceptable) Excel can select B2 and F7:H11 - I'd be happy with with just one block eg F7:H11 - with any previous selection cancelled. Tried googling - but only come up with muti select lists or grids with complete rows or complete columns selected - rather than an inner block postioned somewhere inside the overall columns and rows  - anyone know a good plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Well we solved pretty much all of our grid issues by adopting http://datatables.net/